# What does char pointer zero mean?

Tags: c, pointers

Literally, does `(char *) 0` mean a pointer to some location that contains a zero? Does the system create such an address with value 0 for each such declaration?

Comment: You can create pointers to any bit of memory you want, just by specifying that memory address - after all, memory is "linear" and each byte is directly addressable. Doing so is pretty useless, because generally you have no idea where your data actually is, and pointing at random memory addresses is a good way to crash your app and/or computer.

Comment: @MarcB: That's not what `(char *)0` does... it is a *null pointer* which does not necessarily have address zero (although it usually does).  Using the literal `0` here has special meaning... it is not the same as `(char *) 1 - 1` for example.

Comment: BTW, memory is not necessarily linear.

Comment: An operating system may or may not have a `'\0'` (the null character) at address `0` (a null pointer).  A C program may not de-reference a null pointer.  So from a C point-of-view, the value at address 0 is unknowable.

Comment: @chux well, from a strict point of view, the value at any particular numbered address is unknowable. (And addresses might not correspond to numbers anyway). Address zero isn't special in this regard, except that you might have to get to it by pointing to address `1` and decrementing!

Comment: @chux address 0 is not necessarily the same as the null pointer, just that a 0 in a pointer context results in the null pointer constant. The implementation is free to make writing `(void *)0` result in a ANY value for the pointer so long as it's always the same and it is never the same as a legal address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's a cast of `0` to type `char *`.  That is, a *null pointer*.  A `0` in any pointer context refers to the *null pointer constant*.

*What* exactly it points to doesn't matter - dereferencing it would cause undefined behaviour.

For more, check out the [C FAQ Part 5: Null Pointers](http://c-faq.com/null/).

Comment: @DietrichEpp, I'm familiar with how null pointers work; it's logically not a pointer at all really. Edited to clarify.

Comment: "What exactly it points to doesn't matter". Actually, it points per definitionem nowhere. Some compilers have an extension which allows reading memory location 0 some other way, like with a volatile null-pointer or some such marker.

Comment: @Deduplicator that's exactly the difference between *what* it points to and *where* it points.  The latter might have meaning, but the former certainly doesn't.

Comment: @Deduplicator or they just allow dereferencing null pointer to access address 0, and don't make it trap.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: There's a good reason no modern compiler does that: It removes a huge chunk of optimization possibilites, which means they produce much bigger and slower code than their competition, thus they are soon forgotten or they mend their ways really fast.

Comment: @Deduplicator example of such a lost possibility?   I have coded for system that allowed reading and writing address 0 this way, although it didn't have any competition!  (Hardware manufacturer also put together the only development kit)

Comment: @Matt: Any time the compiler cannot with its limited knowledge and restricted static reasoning deduce that a pointer cannot be `NULL` without assuming that the programmer is correct in dereferencing it. A famous case where the Linux kernel developers got it wrong was uncovered when the GCC crew started exploiting that. Don't have a reference handy though, sorry.

Comment: Could explain why -O3 always made the program crash on startup on that platform

Comment: @DietrichEpp Yes, it may not be address 0, but as the question now says, casting 0 to a pointer type results in the null pointer constant, which may have a value other than 0.

Comment: @Spudd86: The comment was in response to an earlier version of the answer.  The earlier version doesn't appear in the edit history because it occurred in the five-minute window after an answer is posted.

Answer (score 3):

It is null pointer value of type `char *`.

From the C++ Standard

> A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result
>   is **the null pointer value of that type**

And from the C Standard

> 3 An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an
>   expression cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant.66)
>   If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the
>   resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare
>   unequal to a pointer to any object or function.
>
> 4 Conversion of a null pointer to another pointer type yields **a null
>   pointer of that type**. Any two null pointers shall compare equal.

It is not a pointer that points to a locarion that contains 0. So the system creates nothing. As it is written in the C Standard the null pointer "is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function". So it is used to determine whether a pointer points to some object or function.

Answer (score 0):

its an explicit cast to a null pointer. i believe there is a #define macro for it allowing you to just write NULL

Comment: if someone sees this. can someone explain why i got +8 rep for this?

Comment: Yeah you get +10 for upvotes and -2 for downvotes, hence the "+8" for this question.